# sum of two independent scaled noncentral $\chi$-squared random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation, independence, gamma-distribution, chi-squared

I want to analyze or *approximate* a random variable that is a sum of two scaled independent non central $\chi$-squared random variables with the same degrees of freedom.

For example,
$$X = X_1 + a X_2$$
where $X_1 \sim \chi^2(k,\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \chi^2(k,\lambda_2)$, $k$ is the degree of freedom, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are noncentral parameters.

Simulations show that pdf of $X$ has the form of non central $\chi$-squared, or Gamma, ... I did try using characteristic function $M_X(t) = M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(at)$ but it does not seem that the inverse transform of $M_X(t)$ has analytic form.

I wonder if there exists well-known results for this kind of problems.

For example,

$k=7, l_1=2,l_2=5, a=3$
[image]

$k=7, l_1=2,l_2=5, a=1$
[image]

$k=7, l_1=2,l_2=5, a=-1$
[image]

Comment: You have $X= X_1 + aX_2.$ There is a standard and well known answer in case $a=1.$ If $a\ne1,$ I suspect there is no closed form.

Answer (score 0):

There is one case which is well-known.

**Lemma**. Let $Q_i \sim \chi^2_{k_i}(\lambda_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, be independent. Then, $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n Q_i$ is a noncentral-$\chi^2_{k}(\lambda)$, where $k=\sum_{i=1}^n k_i$ and $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$.

**Proof**. The Moment Generating Function (MGF) of $Q_i$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{M}_{Q_i}(t) = (1 -2t)^{-k_i/2} \exp \Big\{ \frac{\lambda_i t}{1 - 2t} \Big\}
$$
The MGF of $Q$, using independence, is given by
$$
\mathcal{M}_Q(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{M}_{Q_i}(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 -2t)^{-k_i/2} \exp \Big\{ \frac{\lambda_i t}{1 - 2t} \Big\} = (1 - 2t)^{- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n k_i} \exp \Big\{ \frac{t}{1 - 2t} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \Big\}
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathcal{M}_Q(t) = (1 -2t)^{-k/2} \exp \Big\{ \frac{\lambda t}{1 - 2t} \Big\}
$$
and the thesis immediately follows. $\blacksquare$

Note that, if $\lambda \neq 0$, the PDF (probability density function) of $Q$ does not admit a closed-form, as it involves Bessel functions.

The general case of a linear combination of independent $\chi^2_{k_i}(\lambda_i)$
$$
Q = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i Q_i
$$
results in a so-called [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). The probability density function (PDF) of the generalized $\chi^2$ is also complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, this does not answer my question.

Comment: Can you please better explain your question?

Comment: If I follow your reasoning, the distribution I am looking at must be generalized chi squared distribution and its PDF is complicated. It is the definition. However, simulations show that the PDF looks like the one of scaled/non-central chi squared, etc. My question is whether we can *approximate* my interested PDF to a chi-squared-like PDF.